# Error al instalar extensión solr apache

Tags: ubuntu

Intento instalar solr  y  no he tenido éxito la consola me arroja el resultado de la imagen siguiente al ejecutar **sudo pecl install solr**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

intento instalar  **sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como solucionarlo estos pasos son los que quiero seguir para instalar laextension:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
   sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev
   sudo apt-get install php-pear
   sudo pecl install solr
   sudo sh -c "echo 'extension=solr.so' > /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/solr.ini"
   sudo sh -c "echo 'extension=solr.so' > /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/solr.ini"
   sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Hola. No es claro por qué cancelas la instalación de PHP. Sobre todo porque en el primer comando, todo indica que no tienes PHP instalado...

Comment: si, si tengo php  instalado tengo 7.0  y  ubuntu 16.04 @Alfabravo

Comment: EN la imagen que muestras, abortaste la instalación de PHP7.